# Авторизация на freelance.ru

Tags: авторизация, https

Хочу авторизоваться на сайте, но не получается. Соединение происходит через https, и снифером не подглядеть, какие запросы уходят при авторизации. Я отправляю запрос параметрами login, passwd, remember_me, check_ip на адрес https://freelance.ru/login, но в ответ приходит страница, в которой я не авторизован.

Comment: @azaznioo, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

F12 - Network - ваш друг. Там вы можете увидеть, что еще отправляются параметры auth: auth и submit, который почему-то не раскодировался хромом. Кроме того, уходит cookie user_id, что в нем лежит - неизвестно, но проставляется он сервером при первом запросе. И последнее, что нам нужно для реверс-инженерии - это метод запроса, в данном случае это POST.